# Sum and Average Data into Table from Seperate Table based on Date Intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, r, sum

I have growth data of trees for the month of June across multiple years. Around the beginning of June in 2012, 2013 and 2014, I planted seeds and went back to those seeds near the end of the month to see if the seeds germinated and the tree was alive, or didn't germinate and the tree was dead. For each sample (each seed), the number of growing days were calculated.

```
Sample_ID   Tree_Type   Check_Date  Growing_Days    Status  Max_Temp    Min_Temp    Mean_Temp   Total_mm_Rain
1   Spruce  25-06-2012  16  Alive               
2   Spruce  28-06-2012  25  Alive                
3   Fir 23-06-2012  19  Dead                
4   Spruce  29-06-2012  23  Alive               
5   Fir 28-06-2012  16  Alive               
6   Fir 25-06-2013  18  Alive               
7   Fir 26-06-2013  15  Dead                
8   Spruce  28-06-2013  17  Alive               
9   Fir 30-06-2013  24  Dead                
10  Fir 27-06-2013  19  Alive               
11  Spruce  21-06-2014  16  Alive               
12  Fir 24-06-2014  18  Alive               
13  Fir 28-06-2014  14  Dead                
14  Spruce  29-06-2014  18  Alive               
15  Spruce  30-06-2014  15  Dead
```

What I would like to is see how weather affected my trees. I have pulled historical weather data as a separate dataframe and would like to add to each sample row the Total_mm_Rain that fell during the growing days, along with Max, Min and Mean Temperatures of that growing period.

```
Date    Max_Temp    Min_Temp    Mean_Temp   Total_mm_Rain
01-05-2012  9   3   6   0
02-05-2012  9   2.5 5.8 0
03-05-2012  9.5 -2.5    3.5 4.6
04-05-2012  11  2.5 6.8 0.6
05-05-2012  10  2   6   1.8
06-05-2012  14  -2  6   0
07-05-2012  18  -2  8   0
08-05-2012  21.5    1   11.3    0
09-05-2012  17.5    4.5 11  2.8
10-05-2012  8   0.5 4.3 0
11-05-2012  14.5    -6  4.3 0
12-05-2012  19.5    -3  8.3 0
13-05-2012  23.5    -1  11.3    0
14-05-2012  25  0.5 12.8    0
15-05-2012  27.5    1.5 14.5    0
16-05-2012  24  2.5 13.3    0
17-05-2012  15.5    4.5 10  10
18-05-2012  12.5    2   7.3 0.4
19-05-2012  15  -2  6.5 0
20-05-2012  17.5    -2  7.8 0.4
21-05-2012  15.5    6.5 11  2.2
22-05-2012  12.5    8   10.3    0.4
23-05-2012  14  5   9.5 9.6
24-05-2012  10  1   5.5 1
25-05-2012  11  3   7   3
26-05-2012  13  2   7.5 0
27-05-2012  11.5    3   7.3 0
28-05-2012  17.5    3   10.3    1.2
29-05-2012  15.5    4   9.8 0.2
30-05-2012  17.6    4   10.8    0
31-05-2012  16  6.5 11.3    0.2
01-05-2013  11.5    -4.9    3.3 0
02-05-2013  17.1    -4.5    6.3 2
03-05-2013  15  5.1 10.1    0
04-05-2013  18.9    -0.2    9.4 0
05-05-2013  24.2    -1.8    11.2    0
06-05-2013  26.6    -0.1    13.3    0
07-05-2013  21.9    1.5 11.7    0
08-05-2013  24.6    4.9 14.8    0
09-05-2013  25.5    0.9 13.2    0
10-05-2013  21.4    2   11.7    0
11-05-2013  26.2    3.9 15.1    0
12-05-2013  25  4.5 14.8    0.2
13-05-2013  19.9    10.2    15.1    11
14-05-2013  13.1    5   9.1 0.2
15-05-2013  17.2    -1.7    7.8 0
16-05-2013  15.3    4.1 9.7 0 
17-05-2013  18.6    2.4 10.5    1.6
18-05-2013  15.5    3   9.3 5.6
19-05-2013  12.7    5.6 9.2 1
20-05-2013  22  5   13.5    0
21-05-2013  21.9    1.9 11.9    0
22-05-2013  12  7   9.5 24.8
23-05-2013  7.3 0.1 3.7 4.6
24-05-2013  12.3    1.5 6.9 0.2
25-05-2013  13.7    3.7 8.7 0
26-05-2013  19  -1.5    8.8 0
27-05-2013  20  3.5 11.8    0
28-05-2013  17  5.5 11.3    0
29-05-2013  20.1    7   13.6    0.8
30-05-2013  13.5    7.5 10.5    2.4
31-05-2013  9.9 7   8.5 7.8
01-06-2014  8.8 -1  3.9 3.6
02-06-2014  11.4    0.5 6   0
03-06-2014  11.6    -0.7    5.5 0
04-06-2014  16.9    -3.6    6.7 0
05-06-2014  19.6    -2.3    8.7 0
06-06-2014  16.7    0.9 8.8 0
07-06-2014  9.3 5   7.2 1
08-06-2014  10.1    2.8 6.5 0.4
09-06-2014  13.3    -5.2    4.1 0
10-06-2014  16  -4.3    5.9 0
11-06-2014  17  -1.5    7.8 1.6
12-06-2014  13.9    4.7 9.3 0.3
13-06-2014  16.5    -3.4    6.6 0
14-06-2014  22.9    -2.3    10.3    0
15-06-2014  27  0.6 13.8    0
16-06-2014  29.6    4.1 16.9    0
17-06-2014  29.1    3.3 16.2    0
18-06-2014  28.1    5.6 16.9    0
19-06-2014  25.9    8.1 17  0.2
20-06-2014  15.9    8.7 12.3    3.1
21-06-2014  21.3    8.8 15.1    0.4
22-06-2014  23.7    6.7 15.2    6.9
23-06-2014  18.4    9.3 13.9    0
24-06-2014  18.2    4   11.1    6.4
25-06-2014  16  6.5 11.3    10
26-06-2014  12.2    3.6 7.9 1.9
27-06-2014  11.6    3.5 7.6 2.6
28-06-2014  13.7    4.4 9.1 5.6
29-06-2014  11.7    5.5 8.6 3.4
30-06-2014  17.4    7   12.2    0
```

I have tried using table functions as well as diving into the idea of converting dates to numbers (as in excel) and summing based on dates as numbers instead of dates, but this is above my knowledge of R.

Comment: If you want to convert dates into numbers, you should use the as.Date function to convert strings to date values.  Note that there's a format portion if your dates aren't in a commonly recognized, unambiguous format.  

I can't tell if this is one of the issues you had, or if it just lead to a dead end for you, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried the merge by date as well, but the issue there is each row in the growth dataset has multiple days worth of weather data that need to be pooled first.

Comment: ex. in sample 1, I need to somehow sum the total amount of rainfall starting 09-06-12 (16 days prior to check date) and ending on the check date of 25-06-12. With those same dates, I would also like to get the average temperature, min temp and max temp. Sorry if this is unclear in my original message.

Comment: I Just Noticed I gave the wrong month for the weather data. Ill have to edit and repost! Sorry!